# Sequelize ordering with nested associations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have an included model where I need to sort by the same property but with two conditionals.

```
 include:[{
      model: EventType,
      include: { model: EventType, as: 'parent' },
 }],
```

They have property parentId in the DB and when data is read it looks like this

**If it has parent:**

```
eventType: {
  name: 'Some other name' // this is default name prop same as parents
  parentId: 1,
  parent: { name: 'Somename' }
}
```

**If not**

```
eventType: {
  name: 'another name'
  parentId: null,
  parent: null
}
```

I want to sort by name, but if eventType has **'parent'** to use parents name for sorting.

My ordering property looks like this:

```
order: [
 [{ model: EventType, as: 'parent' }, 'name', sorting],
 [{ model: EventType }, 'name', sorting],
]
```

So this is always looking just name property and looking for parent's name.  Does anyone knows what could be the problem?